# Name cannot begin with the '3' character, hexadecimal value 0x33

Tags: c#, xml

```
xds.Data = tree.Getxml();

xds.EnableCaching = false;

treeview.DataSource = xds;

treeview.DataBind();
```

When I bind the treeview , I am getting this error, my xml are given below

```
<Spaces 
    CustomSpaceId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
    CreatedUserId="1" CreatedDate="5/28/2013 3:16:32 PM" 
    SpaceType="1" 
    ParentID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
    SelectAction="Select" 
    ToolTip="Shared">
    <Quick-Case 
        CustomSpaceId="fcf87b0e-b571-41dc-a880-86c26f76eda6" 
        CreatedUserId="1" CreatedDate="5/16/2007 2:28:03 PM" 
        SpaceType="2" ParentID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
        SelectAction="Select" 
        ToolTip="private">
        <![CDATA[Quick-Case]]>
        <New_Space_1 
            CustomSpaceId="1b0b82d2-b1d2-4809-b152-8eba3ac335ab" 
            CreatedUserId="2" 
            CreatedDate="2/22/2013 12:23:00 PM" 
            SpaceType="2" 
            ParentID="fcf87b0e-b571-41dc-a880-86c26f76eda6" 
            SelectAction="None" ToolTip="Blocked">
            <![CDATA[New_Space_1]]>
        </New_Space_1>
    </Quick-Case>
    <Personal-Case 
        CustomSpaceId="c2fe1da8-4c36-49b3-884f-6832b508c5bd" 
        CreatedUserId="1" 
        CreatedDate="5/4/2007 12:36:07 PM" 
        SpaceType="0" 
        ParentID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
        SelectAction="Select" 
        ToolTip="private">
        <![CDATA[Personal-Case]]>
    </Personal-Case>
    <3 
        CustomSpaceId="82d0be9f-030f-490b-bc4d-52b0cfcef72a" 
        CreatedUserId="1" 
        CreatedDate="5/28/2013 10:56:54 AM" 
        SpaceType="1" 
        ParentID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
        SelectAction="Select" ToolTip="Shared">
        <![CDATA[3]]>
    </3>
</Spaces>
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: Generate a valid xml. `</3>` is not a valid tag.

Comment: but i need to show that integer 3 in my treeview.is there any other alternatives to do this?

Comment: can't you add some header to your custom names? `My3` or `CustomeName3` ?

Comment: nop..need to display the exact customer input.

Comment: You might want to consider not putting data into the element names at all.  Instead you could name all the child elements something like `CustomSpace` the values like `3` would stay in the `CDATA`s or you could move them to attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You've got invalid XML in the last inner element. If you need to display 3 (i.e. the CDATA value) then put that value into an attribute and give your xml a valid element name.

```
<Spaces CustomSpaceId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ..snip...>
   <Quick-Case ...snip...>
       <![CDATA[Quick-Case]]>
           <New_Space_1 ...snip...>
              <![CDATA[New_Space_1]]>
           </New_Space_1>
   </Quick-Case>
   <Personal-Case CustomSpaceId="c2fe1da8-4c36-49b3-884f-6832b508c5bd" ...snip...>
      <![CDATA[Personal-Case]]>
   </Personal-Case>

   <-- THIS BLOCK IS INVALID - YOU CAN'T HAVE AN XML Element CALLED '3' -->
   <3 CustomSpaceId="82d0be9f-030f-490b-bc4d-52b0cfcef72a" ... snip...>
        <![CDATA[3]]>
   </3>
  </Spaces>
```

Comment: not sure why the -1. You asked what you can do. I've told you. rename that element.